# Idiom "off the rack" and the definition from dictionaries and the usage in a sentence "off the rack policy"

Tags: american-english

There is a line from [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/less-than-half-of-americans-support-student-loan-forgiveness-poll-183840781.html), saying,

> High-income households and college graduates—which are more likely to have higher amounts of student debt— were more likely to support forgiveness. Fifty percent of households making more than $100,000 per year support forgiveness, compared to 45% of households making less than $50,000. Fifty-three percent of college graduates support forgiveness, versus 35% of people with a high school education or less.

> "It's basically an **off-the-rack policy** to give money to upper-middle class, highly educated people and not others," said Jason Delisle with the American Enterprise Institute. "I don't think it's a good policy because I don't think that's a group of people that we should be providing aid to, necessarily, at the expense of others."

According to 3 dictionaries, the idiom "off the rack" means,

[**1**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-the-rack), [**2,**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+rack), [**3**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-the-rack)

> bought, mass-produced, ready-made.

So is the article trying to say

"Hey dude, it's a supermarket policy to give money to high-income people, nothing original"?

Thank you in advance(m_m).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Off the rack" comes from the clothing world, where it means a suit that you buy without any alterations for sleeves or cuffs or the like, for fit. So in this case, it means a policy that's already in place somewhere else and brought over and applied without any changes.

Answer (score 16):

There are a ***lot*** of written instances of [***off-the-shelf policy***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22off-the-shelf%20policy%22) in Google Books (which ignores hyphens when matching search strings, but they would *usually* be included). By contrast, there are only half-a-dozen instances of ***off-the-rack policy*** (which will always mean *exactly* the same thing).

It's just a relatively "transparent" *metaphorical* usage alluding to the fact that in the *retail* industry, products that are presented on shelves / racks are usually ***mass-produced*** (so they're all the same; "generic", not "custom-designed").

---

But OP has missed the all-important point that it's a ***metaphorical*** usage. The writer isn't *actually* talking about the retail industry or supermarkets at all - he's talking about Joe Biden's plan to "write off" student loan debt. Which is a "knee-jerk, simplistic, off-the-shelf" policy (I would have said "populist", but apparently most Americans *don't* support the policy, so it's not *that*).

In the specific context, it's a ***disparaging*** description, intended to imply the policy ***hasn't been properly thought through***. It just follows conventional Democrat thinking - partly because it just throws money at the problem, and partly because "giving" money to the middle classes (and their college-educated children) is how politicians and bankers often seek to revive their damaged national economy.

Comment: >But OP has missed the all-important point that it's a metaphorical usage. The writer isn't actually talking about the retail industry or supermarkets at all.....In the specific context, it's a disparaging description, intended to imply the policy hasn't been properly thought through. --->Did you see my last remark "nothing original"?

Comment: Yes, I saw that line in your question text. But you wrote ***it's supermarket policy*** in that same sentence - I was just making the point that the usage doesn't ***directly*** concern supermarkets at all (and it wouldn't surprise me to learn that ***off-the-shelf*** predates ***supermarket*** anyway). In any case, the metaphoric usage is more rooted in ***clothing*** sales (tailors) rather than supermarkets and grocery shopping. Another form of exactly the same idiom is [*an **off-the-peg** plan*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+off-the-peg+plan%22) (pegs on clothes racks).

Comment: But you didn't mention nowhere this originates from the clothing world....I love the U.S English so don't play with me kindly!.

Comment: I don't understand your point. I've just checked the full Oxford English Dictionary, and apparently idiomatic ***off-the-shelf*** was first recorded in 1936 (5 years ***after*** their first citation for ***supermarket***). But ***off-the-peg*** (which means the same) was first recorded in ***1879*** (in a *second-hand* clothing context). Whatever - it makes no difference exactly what shelf, peg, or rack the original metaphoric "product" came from. All that matters today is they all mean "standard, "ready-made", as opposed to ***bespoke, tailor-made***.

Comment: You are perfectly missing your own goal. Give me a nicer answer next time. lol. Have a good night.

Comment: I'm sorry if something I've said has upset you, but I've no idea what it might be.

Comment: I'm not sure the author means it isn't thought through, I think they mean that the policy is one of many that's intended to give aid mostly to middle class families while having a veneer of equal distribution which Democrats are endorsing primarily because they think they can sell it to both their lower class and middle class base.  I agree that the metaphor isn't great because it's hard to figure out what they mean by it though.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian: It ***is*** a bit confusing when we get down to the specifics of ***exactly*** what Delisle meant by it. There's no doubt it's intended to be "disparaging" (which certainly isn't always the case with this/these idiomatic usages). But even while I was writing my text after the words ***intended to imply...*** I realised I couldn't really justify any of it. (That was basically just me pitching in with ***my*** "off-the-peg, previously-constructed, stock-in-trade" political prejudices! :)

Answer (score 3):

It's awkward in that sentence. It doesn't really mean anything. I can tell from context it means "bad", but otherwise it means the person from AEI was in a hurry and couldn't think of a better phrase.

"Off the rack" can be a snobbish expression meaning lacking taste and refinement. A wealthy woman has her dress tailored by her maids. Saying it looks off-the-rack means she's so poor that she had to buy a dress at a store and couldn't even afford to have it altered to fit nicer.

It's also a way to say that something is just regular. You got it from a store the same as anyone else could: "your car runs smooth -- does it have a custom carburetor?" "Nope -- off the rack, but I hand-tuned it".

Neither of those really make sense for a student loan debt forgiveness program.

Comment: Okay....thank you very much for your new information anyway though.